# ERROR: Failed to resolve: core Affected Modules: app

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

i updated android studio to version 3.5 and started new project and there is a mistake in gradle files i couldn't understand it what should i do ? i don't understand how gradle files work, 
so would someone commanded to me a course or website teeth how is it work ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hibaadil.myapplication897"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: what exactly the problem is? Android Studio should suggest a quick fix. maybe it is asking you to change targetsdk and compilesdk versions to 29 (android q or 10)? look for yellow or red light bulbs, red underlines or error line where error is occuring.

Comment: also make sure you are connected to the internet on system running Android Studio for gradle to synchronize, if gradle fails to sync goto file ->settings -> build, execution & development -> gradle and untick "work offline" if it is ticked then try again.

Comment: Gradle user guide for Android: https://developer.android.com/studio/build

Comment: thank you very much ,i looked at the yellow lines and i think i had to change these implementation lines to another  versions that he recommended to me and i did that and i think it works ! thanks.